# Server is initiating a GET request on its own after the client is disconnected on apache with request for data

Tags: websocket, socket.io

we have a front end of Angular, backend on Node.js, Apache as web server and socket.io install, when a user refreshes the browser (client) the apache gets a GET request with transport=websocket for the session ID which has been closed/disconnected, which is what it should get as the previous session was keep alive and apache will receive it when the connection closes.

The issue is that our node.js socket.io implementation is responding to the request with 200 status, now when the server responds with 101 as the session ID is already disconnected that packet out will essentially be lost in transit.

Should we be responding with 101 at all, or instead invalidate the request with 400?